# remove time from DatePicker

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to remove time from DatePicker i tried this but facing this error "the getter day was called on null" i am using initial date from firbase profile.date

DateFormat and TextEditingController:

```
var myFormat = DateFormat('d-MM-yyyy');
TextEditingController _datecontroller = new TextEditingController();
```

This is from where the dialog is called:

```
ListTile(
  title: Text('Select DOB'),
  leading: Icon(Icons.calendar_today),
  subtitle: TextField(
    controller: _datecontroller,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      hintText: ('${myFormat.format(_profile?.dob)}'),
    ),
  ),
  onTap: () => _selectDate(context),
),
```

And the selectDate function:

```
Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
  final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: _profile?.dob ?? DateTime(2000),
    firstDate: DateTime(1950),
    lastDate: DateTime.now(),
  );
  if (picked != null && picked != _profile?.dob) {
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    _profile?.dob = picked;
    _bloc.dispatch(UpdateEvent(_profile));
  }
}
```